# Is there any alternative to the Quiz module?

Tags: 7

I like the [Quiz](http://drupal.org/project/quiz) module but its affiliated modules are not ported to D7.

Is there any alternative to the Quiz module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Webform is an option. You can show different questions in different page (something that quiz doesnot do). You will require little bit of programming to show the answers for the questions and their scores once the webform is being submitted. This is if you want to capture the score.